# Compound possession

Tags: compound-possessives

In the following sentence:

> Lewis and Clark's expectations were very much the same.

Would you agree that it should be:

> Lewis's and Clark's expectations were very much the same.

Because even though they were similar, they were not the same, therefore they are different and the apostrophe should be use in both pronouns to show difference.

Any opinion is welcomed.